# When I use created_at__range to specify a range, the range is shifted by one day

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using the filter "created_at__range" to specify the first and last day of the month, but this code doesn't reflect the data registered today.

```
        this_month = datetime.datetime.today()
        first_day = datetime.datetime(this_month.year, this_month.month, 1)
        this_month = this_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        first_day = first_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        time = obj.filter(created_at__range=(first_day, this_month)).aggregate(
            time=Sum('time'))['time']
```

Currently, I'm using timedelta(days=1) to add a day, but if I do this, for example, if the date is 3/31, it will be 4/1 and the tally will be wrong.

```
this_month = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
```

Why is this happening?
If anyone knows how to improve it, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Is created_at a datetime?  If so, the time portion will make it later than 'this_month', which has no time, and is implicitly 0:00

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
How do I deal with the case where created_at is a datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your field `created_at` is a `DateTimeField`. Quoting the warning from [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#range)

> **Warning**
>
> Filtering a **DateTimeField** with dates won’t include items on the
> last day, because the bounds are interpreted as “0am on the given
> date”. If **pub_date** was a **DateTimeField**, the above expression
> would be turned into this SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT ... WHERE pub_date BETWEEN '2005-01-01 00:00:00' and '2005-03-31 00:00:00';
> ```
>
> Generally speaking, you can’t mix dates and datetimes.

I would like to add why even convert the datetime to a string simply use the object in your query:

```py
this_month = datetime.datetime.today()
first_day = datetime.datetime(this_month.year, this_month.month, 1)
time = obj.filter(
    created_at__range=(first_day, this_month)
).aggregate(time=Sum('time'))['time']
```

**Edit**: In fact to make this a little easier for yourself and if there is no object that would have a datetime in the future, just let the ORM and database do a little more work if needed by just comparing the day and the year:

```py
today = datetime.datetime.today()
time = obj.filter(
    created_at__year=today.year,
    created_at__month=today.month,
).aggregate(time=Sum('time'))['time']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For clarity, I tried with `obj.filter(created_at__range=(first_day, this_month)).count()`, but it doesn't work with `created_at__range=(first_day, this_month)` and `created_at__month=3`, the result value is off by 1.
If I count manually, the result is the same as `created_at__month=3` and `created_at__range=(first_day, this_month)` is one less result.
Why is this?

Comment: @space_pok do you use the date string for that query or like I suggested use the datetime objects themself? Anyway check my edit if you find this a little complicated.

Comment: For created_at, we register datetime with created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now).
I've tried what you've edited, but the result is still 1 less than normal.

Comment: @space_pok I believe then that is simply because you are getting results from some past / future year when you write only `created_at__month=3`.